# Possible Paths [HackerRank]

Tags: math

Please see the following Question recently posted on HackerRank

> Adam is standing at point (a,b) in an infinite 2D grid. He wants to know if he can reach point (x,y) or not. The only operation he can do is to move to point (a+b,b), (a,a+b), (a-b,b), or (a,a-b) from some point (a,b). It is given that he can move to any point on this 2D grid,i.e., the points having positive or negative X(or Y) co-ordinates.Tell Adam whether he can reach (x,y) or not.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-jun14/challenges/possible-path

I realized that both x and y must be a sum of some multiple of a and b...

So x%(a+b) OR x%(a-b) should be divisible by either a or b
and similarly for y...

But the following does not work ...

```
    long long int xb,yb,xa,ya;
    xb = x % b;
    xa = x % a;
    yb = y % b;
    ya = y % a;

    // for x
    bool cxbaplusb = a+b==0 ? xb == 0: (xb%(a+b))==0;
    bool cxbaminb = a-b==0 ? xb == 0: (xb%(a-b))==0;

    // for y
    bool cybaplusb = a+b==0 ? yb == 0: (yb%(a+b))==0;
    bool cybaminb = a-b==0 ? yb == 0: (yb%(a-b))==0;

    // for x
    bool cxaaplusb = a+b==0 ? xa == 0: (xa%(a+b))==0;
    bool cxaaminb = a-b==0 ? xa == 0: (xa%(a-b))==0;

    // for y
    bool cyaaplusb = a+b==0 ? ya == 0: (ya%(a+b))==0;
    bool cyaaminb = a-b==0 ? ya == 0: (ya%(a-b))==0;

    if ( (cxbaplusb || cxbaminb || cxaaplusb || cxaaminb)  && (cybaplusb || cybaminb || cyaaplusb || cyaaminb) )        
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
```

But this is not working ...  Am I missing any conditions ? Any suggestions ??

Comment: "It is given that he can move to any point on this 2D grid"/"whether he can reach". What's the difference between "move to a point" and "reach a point"? The problem states that he can move to any point, and asks if he can reach a given point?

Comment: I think it means that,  after a certain steps can he reach x,y if he initially started from a,b. For this problem we can consider "moving to  point" to be same as "reaching a point"

Comment: http://garakchy.blogspot.in/2014/06/hackerrank-ad-infinitum-math_16.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following mathematical explanation may help you achieve your goal.

[image]

[image]

Source: https://hr-filepicker.s3.amazonaws.com/infinitum-jun14/editorials/2372-possible-path.pdf

Comment: This might be a great answer, but images are *not* searchable. Nor are they friendly to the disabled. If you wrote this yourself, you should be able to provide a textual version. If you *didn't* write it yourself, you should be giving attribution to the original source, otherwise it is plagiarism (claiming something as your own that is not yours).

Comment: Now, I have shared the source. I think now its ok? @CodyGray

Comment: @CodyGray
Thank you for warning me here. I'll make sure not to repeat such things in future.

Comment: @vin Please, tick mark the solution. If you are content with it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check the input size

1 ≤ a,b,x,y ≤ 10^18

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/possible-path

CPP won't support this much size, it will throw garbage value resulting in wrong answer

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if(b == 0):
        return a
    return gcd(b, a%b)

t=input()
for i in range(t):
    a = map(int, raw_input().split())
    if(gcd(a[0],a[1]) == gcd(a[2],a[3])):
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int a, int b){
    return b ? gcd(b, a%b) : a;
}
int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--){
        int a, b, x, y;
        cin >> a >> b >> x >> y;
        if (gcd(abs(a), abs(b)) == gcd(abs(x), abs(y)))
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. Clear answer will help people understand what you mean and will increase the chance of selecting as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Initially I had same doubt as you , but  its not " x and y must be a sum of some multiple of a and b " because we can move from (a,b) to  any point in (a+b,b), (a-b,b),(a,b+a),(a,b-a) in case if you move (a+b,b) now a=a+b,b=b so for this value of a,b ( not the given one here a is updated to a+b) only you can do the above operation so its not that x and y always must be sum of some multiple of a,b . so that you have to go with gcd method

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a,b,x,y;
        if(gcd(x,y)=gcd(a,b))
            System.out.println("Adam can reach")
        else
            System.out.println("Adam cannot reach")
    }
}
```

Comment: A little context would be nice. And what is gcd()? This does not really provide any useful information.

Comment: gcd is greatest common divisor