# Possible Path [Hackerrank] compilation timeout

Tags: c, path, timeout

I've tried my code on another compiler and all the test cases work. Unfortunately hackerrank's compiler times out. could anyone make some suggestions to make my code more efficient please.

the Problem:
*Adam is standing at point (a,b) in an infinite 2D grid. He wants to know if he can reach point (x,y) or not. The only operation he can do is to move to point (a+b,b), (a,a+b), (a-b,b), or (a,a-b) from some point (a,b). It is given that he can move to any point on this 2D grid,i.e., the points having positive or negative X(or Y) co-ordinates.*

*Tell Adam whether he can reach (x,y) or not.*

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

long int GreatestCommonDivisor(long int a, long int b)
{
    long int div = 1;
    long int res;

    while ( div <= a)
    {
        if ((a % div == 0) && (b % div == 0)) res = div;
        div++;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        long int a, b, x, y;
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld", &a, &b, &x, &y);

        long int p1 = GreatestCommonDivisor(a, b);
        long int p2 = GreatestCommonDivisor(x ,y);

        if ( p1 == p2) printf("YES\n");
        else printf("NO\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your question in code review site if your code compiles as desired and you want a critical analysis

Comment: If it is really the compiler, not your program, that times out, it may be the server's issue. You should use Euclidean algorithm to make your program faster.

Comment: No, that's your job, on a challenge site. That's the point, not just to submit a naive solution that works, but a sharp one that works well.

Comment: Asking people to solve your challenge questions is cheating.

Comment: I already solved it, Im asking for suggestions so that their compiler doesnt timeout.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261070/possible-paths-hackerrank

Comment: No, you have not solved it. If you had, you would get Correct Answer. For all we know, the actual test could give Wrong Answer, when within the time limit. As I said, the *real* problem is finding a slick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need a more efficient algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

long int greatestCommonDivisor(long int m, long int n) {
    long int r;

    /* Check For Proper Input */
    if ((m == 0) || (n == 0))
        return 0;
    else if ((m < 0) || (n < 0))
        return -1;

    do {
        r = m % n;
        if (r == 0)
            break;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }
    while (true);

    return n;
}

char *array[12];

int main() {
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long int a, b, x, y;
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld", &a, &b, &x, &y);

        long int p1 = greatestCommonDivisor(a, b);
        long int p2 = greatestCommonDivisor(x, y);

        if (p1 == p2) array[i] = ("YES\n");
        else array[i] = ("NO\n");

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s", array[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your original version also didn't pass the output test, you had to format it.